# Latex: hyperref to individual longtable rows

Tags: latex, label, ref, hyperref, longtable

I have a few longtables that stretch several pages and I want to use pageref and hyperref to link to these rows.

But whatever I try, the links always refer to the start of the table.
When I look into the aux file, the labels all seem to be re-defined into table.[number of table].

I tried putting invisible dummy figures into the table, but that just gives me errors of too many floats.

I also tried putting the labels into minipages, to no avail.

Even putting the labels into footnotes doesn't work, somehow longtable always seems to get to them.

Comment: If you create a minimal example of the problem (e.g., only loading longtable and hyperref and a table full of lorem ipsum text with the non-resolving links) it might be easier for us to track down the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by introducing a custom counter and label command:

```
\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand{\mylabel}[1]{\refstepcounter{mycounter} \label{#1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [This article](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2008-05/msg01417.html) and [The readme for Hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/) you need to include the Hyperref package after you include Longtable

Comment: This is good advice, but unfortunately it doesn't solve this specific problem.